# Galera Cluster is not replicating completely

Tags: mariadb, galera

The situation is simple: I have a Galera Cluster with two nodes. 
I create a new database from a .SQL archive (obtained via mysqldump) in one node. The database is quite big: more or less 500 GB. The other node begins the synchronization but it always stops when the database has reached the same size (4 GB aprox.).
Is there any parameter that limits the process? What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if it helps anyone: The problem is related to the database engine. In this case, it was MyIsam and Galera Cluster only works with Innodb.